# Spring Boot JPA/JsonView Grandchild relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Preface:

- Using Springboot with JPA (MySQL) and JsonViews
- Below `Community` entity works normally on it's own.
- My JsonView I'm trying to use is named Social.
- My ultimate question is how can I fix the code below to either Lazy Load the community tags
- Additionally; is it better to have 3/4 views that are linked to their function; i.e. `Brief` for list operations, `Social` for expanded resources and `Internal` for all data, or is it better to have a view like `UserBrief`, `UserExpanded` and so on?

I have an Entity named `User`, with a `Many-One` relationship called `communities`, which is a set of the `Community` entity. In the `Community` entity, it has a Set of `CommunityTag` entities as a `Many-Many` relationship. All child relationships are Lazy loaded.

I get the following error:

```
Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: core.models.
Community.tags:
```

Below is the relevant code of both Entities and the UserRepository class
User class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter @Setter
    @JsonView({Views.Brief.class})
    private Integer id;
    ...
    @Getter @Setter
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonView({Views.Social.class})
    Set<Community> communities = new HashSet<>();
```

Community:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "communities")
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Community implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter @Setter
    @JsonView({Views.Brief.class, Views.Internal.class, Views.Social.class})
    private Integer id;
    ...
    @Getter @Setter
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Nullable
    @JoinTable(
            name = "communities_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "community_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonView(Views.Social.class)
    private Set<CommunityTag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}
```

UserRepository, extends JpaRepository:

```java
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"avatar", "banner", "communities"})
    List<User> findAllWithAvatarWithBannerWithCommunitiesByIdNotNull();
```

Thanks for any help provided!